# "Show Maximize Button" property not working in Chrome Version 62

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

"Show Maximize Button" property not working as its suppose to in Chrome browser. I am using Oracle APEX 5 and Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). It is working in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome. I have created a sample page here --> [Oracle APEX Workspace](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=132972)

[image]

You will notice that the region hides and blank screen appears when maximize button is clicked. The region appears again if you try to resize current browser window or change any CSS property from Chrome Developer Tools.

I know a temp. workaround to fix this but looking for permanent solution.

Comment: What is this "Show Maximize Button" you're referring to?

Comment: updated question with more details.